# Error using record and source

Tags: javascript, react-admin

I am currently using React-Admin, and I made a custom Field which have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PriceField = ({ source, record }) =>
    <div>
        <div hidden>
            {window.price = record[source]
                            .replace('[', '')
                            .replace(')', '')
                            .split(',')}
        </div>
        <div>
            Entre {window.price[0]}€ et {window.price[1]}€
        </div>
    </div>

    PriceField.propTypes = {
        label: PropTypes.string,
        record: PropTypes.object,
        source: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

export default PriceField;
```

Called here:

```
<List {...props} title="Fiches Techniques" perPage={10}>
    <Datagrid>
        <TextField label="Marque" source="marque"/>
        <ModelField label="Modele" source="modele"/>
        <TextField label="Garage" source="garage"/>
        <TextField label="Année véhicule" source="annevehicule"/>
        <PriceField source="prix"/>
        <ShowButton/>
    </Datagrid>
</List>
```

When I am for the first time on this page, everything is ok, all is display, but when I go on an other pages and then I go back on it.

I have the error : record[source] is undefined

If someone ever had this problem, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem, I saw that record was an object when I go for the first time on the page, but on the second time, it becomes an array with the object inside.

So I made this function to fix this problem:

```
function isRecord(record) {
    if (record[0] !== undefined)
        return (record[0])
    if (record !== undefined)
        return (record)
}
```

I hope it can help